# Spring Boot two ways for Authentication: Combine LDAP and token based auth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication

For my RESTfulll application, we need to have two kinds of authentications. One is based on LDAP for all internal employees. This is recently implemented and working fine. For all external employees we need some token based authentication.

What do I mean with that? These employees will get send a generated token via email, this token is stored with an expiry date in our database. The employees should be able to “login” with that token. So what would be the best way to implement something like that?

My first thought was to build an additional `ExternalAuthenticationProvider` and add this to the security conf. This works, the users can login with the token as their `username`, they get the JWT. But when they like to access any resources, the response is a `HTTP 403`-error.
For me this implementation looks like a dirty hack, I don’t like the approach, maybe there is better one.

Thanks for any advices.

```
@Component
public class ExternalAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    private ExternalEffortLinkManagementRepository externalEffortLinkManagementRepository;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> gas = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        String userToken = auth.getName();

        ExternalEffortLinkManagement token = externalEffortLinkManagementRepository.getByLink(userToken);

        if (token != null && token.isActive()) {
            gas.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(SecurityConstants.ROLE_EXTERNAL));
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userToken, null, gas);
        } else {
            throw new
                    BadCredentialsException("External system authentication failed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return auth.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide snippets of code of your solution? As to 403 maybe the provider does not set required authorities?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: What authorities does the accessed resources require? 403 suggests the user is authenticated but does not have access rights to the resource - unless the error handling is customized in your app. As to what is best practice - have a look at how spring does it - e.g. OAuth2AuthenticationManager. But I don't think, your approach is wrong as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:

Snippet 1:

```
gas.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(SecurityConstants.ROLE_EXTERNAL)); // ROLE_EXTERNAL = "EXTERNAL"
```

was replaced with

Snippet 2:

```
gas.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + SecurityConstants.ROLE_EXTERNAL));
```

I have used the same code (Snippet 1) for the LDAP authentication, so I just passed the string `"EXTERNAL"` to the `SimpleGrantedAuthority` constructor. But I did this within my `CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator`, seems like spring adds the `ROLE_`-prefix somehow in the hidden code. But this did not work with my `ExternalAuthenticationProvider`, there it was necessary to add `ROLE_` to the string.